# Get selected row in UIPickerView for each component

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have an `UIPickerView` with 3 components populated with 2 `NSMutableArrays` (2 components have the same array).

A tutorial says:

```
//PickerViewController.m
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [arrayColors objectAtIndex:row], row);
}
```

But I want to show the selected row for each component in an `UIAlertView` **after the user touched an UIButton**.

Is there a way to do this? Or must I just use 3 invisible `UILabels` as buffer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Get Selected Value From UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725580/how-to-get-selected-value-from-uipickerview)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So, in your button action method, you can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction) showAlert {
  NSUInteger numComponents = [[myPickerView datasource] numberOfComponentsInPickerView:myPickerView];

  NSMutableString * text = [NSMutableString string];
  for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i) {
    NSUInteger selectedRow = [myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
    NSString * title = [[myPickerView delegate] pickerView:myPickerView titleForRow:selectedRow forComponent:i];
    [text appendFormat:@"Selected item \"%@\" in component %lu\n", title, i];
  }

  NSLog(@"%@", text);
}
```

This would be the absolute formal way to retrieve information (by using the proper datasource and delegate methods), but it might be easier (depending on your set up), to just grab the selected row and then pull the information out of your model directly, instead of going through the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks! selectedRowInComponent is just what I needed.

Comment: Uhm, why are you using an unsigned integer here? -[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] can also return -1 if there's no selected row.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version:

```
var value = ""
for i in 0..<numberOfComponents {
    let selectedRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: i)
    if let s = pickerView.delegate?.pickerView!(pickerView, titleForRow: selectedRow, forComponent: i) {
        value += s
    }
}
```