# How To Get Selected Value From UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know that with a UIDatePicker, you can use something like:

```
NSDate *myDate = picker.date;
```

But I am using a UIPickerView in my view.  How can i similarly get the value selected?  Or do I have to setup didSelectRow type of method to do this?

Update:
This code works for picker with 1 component:

```
NSInteger row;
NSString *weightSelected;

row = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
weightSelected = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

I tired this code for my picker with 2 components, but it is freezing:

```
NSInteger row1, row2;
NSString *weightSelected1;
NSString *weightSelected2;

row1 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
row2 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
weightSelected1 = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row1];
weightSelected2 = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row2];
NSString *weightSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", weightSelected1, weightSelected2];
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can get it in the following manner:

```
NSInteger row;
NSArray *repeatPickerData;
UIPickerView *repeatPickerView;

row = [repeatPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
self.strPrintRepeat = [repeatPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: strPrintRepeat is nothing but a variable which store the string value of PickerView.  That is :- NSString *strPrintRepeat.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I got it working with my picker that has one component.  Can you help modify it though to work with my picker that has 2 components?  I added the exact code I am using for 1 component picker in the question thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this answer...what exactly is repeatPickerData? How is that being populated?

Comment: @yourfriendzak repeatPickerData here I had just declared that but it will not came here. it will came on viewDidLoad method and it contains the value which we are going to display in UIPickerView. Thanks for asking question and if you still have doubts then you are most welcome to ask the question.

Comment: For a little clarification look at it this way. NSLog(@"%@", [self.arrayFields objectAtIndex:[self.queryPicker1 selectedRowInComponent:0]]); Where arrayFields is the data array for the UIPickerView. Where queryPicker1 is the UIPickerView. Where selectedRowInComponent:0 is the first column (if you have 2 columns in your picker and want the value for the 2nd use 1 instead of 0) of the UIPickerView.

Comment: Can you explain the code clearly. Sure, repeatPickerData.

Answer (score 34):

You can get the text of the selected item in any section of the picker using the same function that the pickerView does, from your custom ViewController class:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

using the selected item

```
[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]
```

so to set the text of a label in a custom cell using the currently selected value from the 2nd section of myPickerView (a property of your view controller probably)

```
[cell.label setText:[self pickerView:myPickerView titleForRow:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] forComponent:1]];
```

Just change both :1s to :2s, etc for each section

Comment: +1 - this is significantly better than the current (crap) accepted answer. It's clearer, doesn't use strange variables that haven't been introduced or explained, and doesn't assume (without stating it) that the `UIPickerViewDelegate` is getting the row titles from an array. Frankly, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    selectedEntry = [allEntries objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

The `selectedEntry` is a `NSString` and will hold the currently selected entry in the pickerview. I am new to objective C but I think this is much easier.

Answer (score 6):

You can access the selected row for a given component using the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Otherwise, implementing the delegate function is the only other option.

Comment: Ok, well i currently have a `dimissPicker` method that is called when the submit button is pressed.  I want the value selected to then be saved or to update a button etc when the dissmissPicker method is called.  How can I do this?  Do I need to add the `selectedRowInCompnent` method?

Comment: That is probably the best way to do it, yes

Comment: Ok perfect, can you help me set this up?  I just added the `selectedRowInComponent` method but what exactly do I do with it.  Its supposed to return the value selected.  I have 2 components in the clicker also.

Comment: You can setup the delegate to track the selected value of the picker. Every time the user changes a component, that function will be called. You can use the selected row to get the value out of the array that is being used to fill it, and then save that state in the delegate to access later when you want to save the value permanently

Answer (score 3):

You will need to ask the picker's delegate, in the same way your application does. Here is how I do it from within my UIPickerViewDelegate:

```
func selectedRowValue(picker : UIPickerView, ic : Int) -> String {

    //Row Index
    let ir  = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: ic);

    //Value
    let val = self.pickerView(picker,
                              titleForRow:  ir,
                              forComponent: ic);
    return val!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `didSelectRow` delegate method, because a `UIPickerView` can have an arbitrary number of components.  There is no "objectValue" or anything like that, because that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the selected title of a picker:

```
let component = 0
let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: component)
let title = picker.delegate?.pickerView?(picker, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       NSInteger SelectedRow;
                   SelectedRow = [yourPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
                   selectedPickerString = [YourPickerArray objectAtIndex:SelectedRow];
                   self.YourTextField.text= selectedPickerString;

    // if  you want to move pickerview to selected row then 
 for (int i = 0; I<YourPickerArray.count; i++) {
  if ([[YourPickerArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:self.YourTextField.text]) { 
[yourPickerView selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:NO];
 }
}
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: Ok Sure. Thanks for the Tip

Answer (score -2):

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   weightSelected = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score -5):

This is my answer

```
- (IBAction)Result:(id)sender 
{
   self.statusLabel.text = DataSource[[pickerViewTool selectedRowInComponent:0]];

}
```