# How To Get Selected Value From UIPickerView With 2 Components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a question here where I asked how to get a value form UIPickerView ( [How To Get Selected Value From UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725580/how-to-get-selected-value-from-uipickerview) ).  I got a solution for a picker with 1 component but I'm trying to get the value from picker with 2 component now.

This code works for picker with 1 component:

```
    NSInteger row;
    NSString *weightSelected;

    row = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    weightSelected = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

I tired this code for my picker with 2 components, but it is freezing.  There is no error in the console either.  The line it is freezing at is `row2 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];`
:

```
    NSInteger row1, row2;
    NSString *weightSelected1;
    NSString *weightSelected2;

    row1 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    row2 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    weightSelected1 = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row1];
    weightSelected2 = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row2];
    NSString *weightSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", weightSelected1, weightSelected2];
```

UPDATE:

```
#pragma mark - Weight Picker 
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {
    return 2;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return [pickerArray count];
        if (component == 1)
            return [pickerArrayHalf count];
    }
    else
        return [pickerArray count];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

   // NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [weightArray objectAtIndex:row], row);
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
            int weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", weight];

            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
            [label autorelease];
            return label;
        }

        else
        {
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
            label.text = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
            [label autorelease];
            return label;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        int reps = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d reps", reps];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
        [label autorelease];
        return label;
    }
}
```

Update again:

I added this code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected row: %i", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row], row);
    NSLog(@"Component 0: %@", [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]);
    NSLog(@"Component 1: %@", [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]);
}
```

I now get a crash when scrolling the clicker now at line:     NSLog(@"Component 1: %@", [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]);

error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]:
>   index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

I also got `Component 0: (null)`

Update:

Code for declaring pickerArray:

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i)
        [pickerArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];

    pickerArrayHalf = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"0 lb"];
    [pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"1/2 lb"];
```

Comment: You initWithCapacity:700 and then add 1000 objects to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freezing?  Wear a sweater  :-)  Actually, what does the log say - do you know where it's freezing?  Put NSLog statements to find the exact line, or step through with the debugger.

Comment: Ahh sorry, it is freezing at `row2 = [repPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];`.  There is no output in the console about the error either, the view just freezes.

Comment: Can you post your code where the regPicker is declared, as well as it's delegates?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with the code.  The tag for this picker is #1. (tag #2 is the picker with 1 component for which the code at the beginning of my question works perfectly.)

Comment: I think I may know what my problem is.  The data of the array loading component 0 is of type int, while the data in the array loading component 1 is of type string.  Could this be it?

Comment: Ok, do two things: un-comment the NSLog in didSelectRow:   and  put in an NSLog to check the value returned by  "selectedRowInComponent" - this method can return -1, which would give you an array out-of-bound exception.

Comment: Ok I get an error and crash, details posted in question. thanks.

Comment: The NSSLogs are crashing the app, maybe I implemented them incorrectly?

Comment: No, you implemented the NSLog correctly.  But you have one of two problems.  Either your pickerArray has no contents in it (or does not even exist), or your component is returning -1 which is also not a valid index into the array.  Can you post your code where you declare the UIPickerView and where you declare the pickerArray?  I think they are getting deallocated before you want them to.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted the code where I declared PickerArray.  The UIPickkerView was setup in IB so there really isn't any code other than property, etc.

Comment: Unless you are doing all of your processing in the same method that pickerArray is declared in, it will be deallocated before it is used.  You should declare it as an iVar (in .h with @property etc.) because it's not being retained.  Set  self.pickerArray = < ... > so when you reference it later, it actually has something in it.

Comment: pickerArray actually already is an iVar.  That is why it works for my other picker that has 1 component in it.

Comment: Ok, good. Then something is happening to it between allocation and the time it gets to your NSLog statement, because it's empty.  Put in some more NSLog statements like   NSLog(@"pickerArray count is %d",[self.pickerArray count]);

Comment: For picker with 2 components, I get `2011-04-20 13:03:14.585 Curl[37888:207] pickerArray count is 1001` and `2011-04-20 13:05:22.886 Curl[37915:207] pickerArrayHalf count is 2` so that seems to be ok. pickerArray fills component 1, while pickerArrayHalf loads component 2.

Comment: ahh I got it working now.  The NSLogs are crashing the app but I am able to get the value from the picker.  So I guess its not even worth figuring out why the NSLogs are crashing.

Comment: Well, that's good news. However, NSLog is one of your best friends in iOS development, so it's probably worth figuring it out.   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `NSLog(@"repPicker: %@", repPicker);` could help to figure out what is going on there.

Edit:
You are initializing the pickerArray with capacity 700 and add 1000 objects. This does not work. I would use `pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];` and add the 1000 objects.