# How can I show the selected value from uipickerview to anotherview

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Can anyone tell me how can I show the value from one a UIPickerView in another view? I am storing a value in a label but I have to show this value in a button in another view controller.

Comment: check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725580/how-to-get-selected-value-from-uipickerview

Comment: Are you trying to use in another view like are you going to view or back to view before

Comment: Yes,for example i have button in first View when i tap it. It will move on Second view and selecting some value from picker.Then it will return to first view and show the selected value on button .

Comment: HI,RIP I tried this one but not working pls see my comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would store the value data in your model when the user closes the second view. and the first view would read the value from the model when it re-appears (or use notifications). Your model data could be a plist, or nsuserdefaults or core-data etc.

Alternatively you could create a reference to the first viewController when you create your second viewController and assign this as a property on the second viewController. Then the second viewController in effect has a "path" to the first viewController:

The first viewController would have a property such as:

```
NSString *myStr;  // in the header
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myStr;  // in the header file
@synthesize myStr;  // in the implementation file
```

The second viewController would have a property such as:

```
firstViewController *firstVC;  // in the header
@property (nonatomic, retain) firstViewController *firstVC;  // in the header file
@synthesize firstVC;  // in the implementation file
```

When you create the second viewController you would do something like:

```
secondViewController.firstVC = self;  // in the implementation file
```

Then when you want to update myStr in the first ViewController (from the second viewController) you would do something like:

```
firstVC = @" my new value ";  // in the implementation file
```