# iOS UIPickerView how to get the selected row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

The value of the array is this

```
ListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ListArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Google", @"Samsung", @"Twitter", @"Facebook", @"Apple", @"NiKon", nil];
```

And when you click on the selectButton

```
NSString *select = [ListArray objectAtIndex:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Select : %@", select];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
```

Receive a message box.
When you press OK, I want to go to select the value of the selected file.

But select value is 0.

I do not know how.

Comment: " I want to go to select the value of the selected file." What "file"? There are no files in your code anywhere...

Comment: The file another source file in the project. 
 google Or samsung a part of the file name.

Comment: But then isn't that the part of things you need to be describing? The array and the picker view and the alert are all red herrings. You need to be explaining about these files and what it is you want to do.

Comment: You appear to have the correct answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725580/how-to-get-selected-value-from-uipickerview Now just work through it step by step to find where you have made a mistake.

Comment: We're pretty good at guessing around here, but not that good. You'll need to provide a much more complete example for us to understand the nature of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` in your class and you will get an event when the user selects a row in a component:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // here you can remember the selected row or perform some action
}
```

Don't forget to set your pickerView delegate:

```
self.pickerView.delegate = self; // or other
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

        NSString *selectedValue=[ListArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        NsLog(@"selectedValue:%@",selectedValue);
}
```