# How to connect a uipickerview to a parse database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mongodb, parse-platform

I have a database already set up using Parse (parse.com) and I have text boxes that when you enter something in them they show up in my database. My question for someone is how do I get a preselected item from a uipickerview to go to that same database. All my app does now is allow for people to enter a name, email and phone number (and it works) but now I added a uipickerview and do not know how to get those predetermined items to show up. My uipickerview shows up and it says what I want it to say but I  just have no idea how to do what I want to do..
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have put in my viewcontroller.h:

```
IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
```

Here is my code as of now for my viewcontroller.m:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender {

NSString *nameString = nameField.text;
NSString *emailString = emailField.text;
NSString *phoneString = phoneField.text;




PFObject *newVisitor = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"visitorLog"];
newVisitor[@"name"] = nameString;
newVisitor[@"email"] = emailString;
newVisitor[@"phone"] = phoneString;
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking that your pickerview is already prefilled and when someone selects a row, it queries from that class. So say you have a UIPIckerView with 2 options Class 1 & Class 2. Are you saying when someone scrolls to class 2  that's the class it will query from?

Comment: I want to know how to get what the user selects from the UIPickerView into my database just like I am currently doing however all I am using now are text boxes.

Comment: Then just do a little research. If you had googled this before posting you would have seen hundreds of options to pick from. Since your new to SO I would just take it easy. It's always best to do your own research prior to asking. This shows people like me that our time won't be wasted and that the questioner has actually tried something first. Anyways. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725580/how-to-get-selected-value-from-uipickerview simply add the pickerview delegates to retrieve the object that they select and then save it in your parse backend @Benji576

Comment: Thank you, I ended up making making it so that when I chose an option in my UIPickerView it went to a text field.